# RewriteRule for removing the ".html" extension gives "Internal Server Error"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my .htaccess file setup in my webhosting and it looks like this (I’m trying to remove the .html part of the URL):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Nothing works, no matter what code i use it doesn't work, it gives a error that looks like this :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@(Mywebsitehere.com) and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have emailed my web hosting service but it is no good, please help. Am I missing something huge?

Comment: What URL are you going to and what do you expect to happen? And what does this question have to do with FTP?

Comment: I did not realize ftp was in the tags, i apologize for that. I am working with www.toontownclassic.com/news.html

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Is that returning 500 server error? Where is your htaccess file? Do you have mod_rewrite turned on?

Comment: i want it to remove the .html part of the url. its giving me a error and i don't have mod_rewrite on.

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log to see what the error is.